# cannot get a connection to MySQL in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have this simple code:

```
<?php
//Open the mySQL connection
$conn_string = "'localhost', 'Vale', 'test'";
$dbh = mysql_connect($conn_string);

//Check that a connection with the DB has been established
if (!$dbh) 
{
   die("Error in MySQL connection: " . mysql_error());
}
...
```

And I get the error: Error in MySQL connection: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found.

I cannot figure out what the problem is, I have been google-ing but all the suggestions have failed (tried 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost, 127.0.0.1:3306, etc.)

I have code that works with postgre, but I need to use mysql, and I am trying to modify it, but I cannot pass the first line and get a connection. Any suggestion, please? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`mysql_connect`](https://www.php.net/mysql_connect) doesn't take a comma seperated string. It takes 3 individual strings.
Change it to this:

```
$dbh = mysql_connect($server, $mysql_user, $password);
```

If you absolutely have a comma separated string, and can't get around this, you can split the string like this:

```
 $config = str_replace("'", '', $conn_string); // replace the quotes.
 $config = preg_split('/,/', $conn_string); // split string on ,
 if($config != $conn_string) { // make sure this returned an array
     count($config) === 3 OR die("Invalid database configuration string");
     $dbh = mysql_connect($config[0], $config[1], $config[2]);
     if(FALSE === $dbh) {
         die("Coult not connect: " . mysql_error());
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, I just realized that! New to MySQL, in Postgre it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider MySQLi, instead of MySQL.

```
<?php

$dbh=mysqli_connect("localhost","Vale","Password","test"); /* Vale is your username? And the name of your database if test, right? And your Username's Password is blank? */

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){

echo "Error".mysqli_connect_error();
}

?>
```

Comment: You should probably make it clear for the OP that the 3rd argument that's a blank string is actually the DB password.

Answer (score 0):

[`mysql_connect`](https://www.php.net/mysql_connect) requires three argument not single string

```
$dbh = mysql_connect('localhost', 'Vale', 'test');
```

Answer (score 0):

As other users have pointed out `mysql_connect` expects the database, username, and password as separate arguments rather than a single string.

I think another highly important issue to point out is that this particular extension is deprecated.

Please see: https://www.php.net/function.mysql-connect

A better solution would be to use `mysqli_connect`: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php

```
$db = mysqli_connect( 'localhost', 'Vale', 'test', 'yourDatabaseName' );
```